# Is It possible to add more "menus" in the top panel in gnome

Tags: gnome, gui, menu, customization, panel

I wanted to do a project involving the use of a toggle switch that I was hoping would be located on the top menu bar of gnome near were the network icon, time/date dropdown, power, etc and was wondering if it were possible to do so and if so how?

Comment: some ideas .. I have not tried this myself ... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3166/custom-menu/ .....  search term  "top bar custom"   on gnome extensions site  ... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1037/customcorner/  etc. or search for how to make gnome tweaks.  no help here though on DIY https://extensions.gnome.org/about/